# No puedo instalar lxml

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Estoy tratando de instalar lxml en mi equipo con `pip install lxml` y me arroja el siguiente error:

```
C:\>pip install lxml
Collecting lxml
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/a8/73d795778143be51d8b
86750b371b3efcd7139987f71618ad9f4b8b65543/lxml-4.5.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lxml
  Complete output from command c:\users\administrador\appdata\local\programs\pyt
hon\python38-32\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='C:\\Users\\Administra
dor\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-v6wvpowt\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(open
(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\U
sers\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo9dw1zgspip-wheel-:
  Building lxml version 4.5.1.
  Building without Cython.
  Building against pre-built libxml2 andl libxslt libraries
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isosche
matron
  copying src\lxml\etree.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\etree_api.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes

  copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.w
in32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32
-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32
-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-x
slt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract
_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematr
on-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_inc
lude.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-
xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematr
on_message.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schem
atron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematr
on_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xs
l\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for
_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematro
n-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -
> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  running build_ext
  building 'lxml.etree' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C+
+ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for lxml
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml
    Complete output from command c:\users\administrador\appdata\local\programs\p
ython\python38-32\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users
\\Administrador\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-v6wvpowt\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(
compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'),
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-u7
1f1pvt-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Building lxml version 4.5.1.
    Building without Cython.
    Building against pre-built libxml2 andl libxslt libraries
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual
C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\administrador\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python
.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Administrador\\AppData
\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-v6wvpowt\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize
, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" inst
all --record C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-u71f1pvt-record\install-re
cord.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1
 in C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-v6wvpowt\lxml

C:\>
```

> He probado con el `source` manualmente: `lxml-4.5.1.tar.gz` y tambien me lanza el mensaje de arriba.

> He probado con el `wheel` manualmente `lxml-4.5.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` y dice: `lxml-4.5.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this plataform` (también intenté con 32 bits y versiones anteriores para 32 y 64 bits)

> He probado actualizando `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0`

> Actualice `pip`

Mi versión de python es `3.8.1`, estoy en `Windows 7 Ultimate SP1` con procesador `Pentium(R)Dual-Core CPU E5300`

Y ninguno de esos métodos funciona para mi.

Llevo horas buscando en internet y probando los métodos que he encontrado y aún sigue el problema. Simplemente ya no se que hacer.

Comment: Intenta actualizar Python a la 3.8.3, e instala con `pip install lxml`

Comment: @gabrielcoronel gracias, lo voy a intentar y comento como me fue.

Comment: Actualizar algo que no sea la versión correcta del compilador es inútil a no ser que la nueva versión requiera un compilador que tengas correctamente instalado, el problema es que se requiere MVC 14 y que éste esté accesible en el PATH.

Comment: Si no quieres complicarte, puedes usar binarios precompilados ofrecidos por Christoph Gohlke de la Univ. California: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml. Recuerda que tanto la versión de Python (3.7, 3.8, ...)como la arquitectura (32/64 bits) deben coincidir, tenías instalado **Python 3.8 de 32 bits**, el paquete debe ser para 32 bits, si instalas Python de 64 bits debes instalar paquetes para 64 bits, siempre tenlo en cuenta cuando instalas algo manualmente. Se instalan igual que cualquier otro whl con pip.